# why passing greater buffer size to fgets allowed by compiler

Tags: c, fgets

I have the following code:

```
char str[0]; // 0 length

while(fgets(str, 100, stdin)) { // It works.
   fputs(str, stdout);
}
```

But if I do without loop, then it breaks. like this;

```
  fgets(str, 100, stdin); 
   fputs(str, stdout);
```

Comment: Zero-length array is illegal. But in general, C does not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. If you use a function wrong then it is on your own head what happens.  It might appear to "work" at first and fail later, or it might fail when run on a different machine. It might format your hard drive, etc.

Comment: "*garbage in, garbage out*"

Comment: @tod, using windows. The last one fails without message.

Comment: C generally does little hand-holding: You are expected to do the right thing. That is neccessary to achieve these goals: efficiency and (easy) implementability. You lie to the compiler, you get what you deserve. You don't respect the contratct, dito.

Comment: str is only a pointer, it's up to programmer to check limits. Welcome to C, where nasal demons dwell..;]

Comment: Hey, I used this type of code before when solving UVA problems and most of it are accepted, but I never think of it that time.

Comment: @MattMcNabb zero-length array is not illegal http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: @zoska Zero-length arrays are a GCC extension; they're illegal in standard C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code invokes undefined behavior (you make `fgets()` write past the end of your buffer), so it can do anything it pleases.